Transfering information between dataframe rows
I have a Dataframe in the form of a genealogy tree with the following columns - ("Generation", "Child_name", "child_hair_color", "Parent_name", "parent_hair_color", "parent_eye_color").
The oldest generation has the assigned value "0" in the column generation, the youngest I assume the maximum value.
I'd like to transfer the information about black hair color from daughter to mother, from mother to grandmother, etc. (but it is important to do this step by step not go through whole Dataframe once).
The only one condition is to stop to transfer information when parent_eye_color would be "Hazel".
The example of input dataset:
schema = StructType([StructField('Generation', IntegerType()), StructField('Child_name', StringType()), StructField('child_hair_color', StringType()), StructField('Parent_name', StringType()), StructField('parent_hair_color', StringType()), StructField('parent_eye_color', StringType())])
Data in initial dataset:
rows = [Row(0, "Susan", "Brown", None, None, None ),
Row(1, "Mary", "Blond", "Susan", "Brown", "Green"),
Row(2, "Alexandra", "Grey", "Mary", "Blond", "Blue"),
Row(1, "Robin", "Blond", "Susan", "Brown", "Hazel"),
Row(2, "Rachel", "Brown", "Robin", "Blond", "Blue"),
Row(2, "Mika", "Grey", "Robin", "Blond", "Blue"),
Row(3, "Patricia", "Blond", "Mika", "Grey", "Green)",
Row(4, "Molly", "Black", "Patricia", "Blond", "Green")]
My idea was to use code below (but after running it I don't see any difference between input and output Dataframe). It is important for me that the code would work effectively on big datasets (30-700k rows).
selected_column = "Generation"

# Use function agg() to find min and max from "Generation" column
min_max_values = df.agg(F.min(selected_column).alias("min_value"), F.max(selected_column).alias("max_value")).first()
max_value = min_max_values["max_value"]

# Loop through generations

for current_level in range(max_value , 0, -1):
    df = df.withColumn("parent_hair_color",
                    when((df.child_hair_color == "Black") & (df.Generation == current_level) & (df.parent_eye_color != "Hazel"),
                    ("Black"))
                    .otherwise(F.col("parent_hair_color")))

    df1 = df.filter(df.parent_hair_color == "Black").select(F.col("Parent_name").alias("Parent"))
    df = df.join(df1, df.Child_name == df1.Parent, "left").select(df["*"], df1["Parent"])

    df = df.withColumn("child_hair_color",
                    when(df.Child_name == df.Parent,
                    ("Black"))
                    .otherwise(F.col("child_hair_color")))

    df = df.drop("Parent")

The output which I want to get:
rows = [Row(0, "Susan", "Brown", None, None, None ),
Row(1, "Mary", "Blond", "Susan", "Brown", "Green"),
Row(2, "Alexandra", "Grey", "Mary", "Blond", "Blue"),
Row(1, "Robin", "Black", "Susan", "Brown", "Hazel"),
Row(2, "Rachel", "Brown", "Robin", "Blond", "Blue"),
Row(2, "Mika", "Black", "Robin", "Black", "Blue"),
Row(3, "Patricia", "Black", "Mika", "Black", "Green)",
Row(4, "Molly", "Black", "Patricia", "Black", "Green")]

can you add some sample data? df = createDataframe(dat=[(...), (...), (...), ], schema='generation: int, ...')

Use Window's partition by to partition on family_id and then generation_number. Then use lag and lead functions to transfer row's column values above or below.

@Kashyap
The example of schema of input dataframe is as below:
schema = StructType([StructField('Generation', IntegerType()), StructField('Child_name', StringType()), StructField('child_hair_color', StringType()),
StructField('Parent_name', StringType()), StructField('parent_hair_color', StringType()), StructField('parent_eye_color', StringType())])

@Kashyap Data for dataframe:
rows = [Row(0, "Susan", "Brown", None, None, None ),
Row(1, "Mary", "Blond", "Susan", "Brown", "Green"),
Row(2, "Alexandra", "Grey", "Mary", "Blond", "Blue"),
Row(1, "Robin", "Blond", "Susan", "Brown", "Hazel"),
Row(2, "Rachel", "Brown", "Robin", "Blond", "Blue"),
Row(2, "Mika", "Grey", "Robin", "Blond", "Blue"),
Row(3, "Patricia", "Blond", "Mika", "Grey", "Green)",
Row(4, "Molly", "Black", "Patricia", "Blond", "Green")]

@Kashyap And what I want to achieve as an outcome is:
rows = [Row(0, "Susan", "Brown", None, None, None ),
Row(1, "Mary", "Blond", "Susan", "Brown", "Green"),
Row(2, "Alexandra", "Grey", "Mary", "Blond", "Blue"),
Row(1, "Robin", "Black", "Susan", "Brown", "Hazel"),
Row(2, "Rachel", "Brown", "Robin", "Blond", "Blue"),
Row(2, "Mika", "Black", "Robin", "Black", "Blue"),
Row(3, "Patricia", "Black", "Mika", "Black", "Green)",
Row(4, "Molly", "Black", "Patricia", "Black", "Green")]

@user238607 yes, I thought about it but I need to admit I did not find a proper way to use them - the reason is one parent have few children and for transfering "Black" hair_color I should use more relation between parent-child then only stick to generation (it is as well important but not the main condition here). When you mention "family_id" you mean whole dataset?

Can you update the question with the data and expected output
